# how to use eclipse git 'Compare version with Ancestor'

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse 4.3.2 with egit 3.3 on ubuntu 12.04.
I tried eclipse 4.3.2 with egit 3.2, eclipse 4.3.1 with egit 3.2. Eclipse 4.4 M6 with egit 3.3, all give me the same error.

I setup a local git repository. When I show history and then click on 1 commit and click 'Compare version with Ancestor', I get this error saying 'opening editor failed'

Do you know how can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Here is what I see in .log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 4 0 2014-03-20 12:53:26.436
!MESSAGE Opening Editor Failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.CompareUtils.compare(CompareUtils.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.history.CommitFileDiffViewer.showTwoWayFileDiff(CommitFileD
iffViewer.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.history.CommitFileDiffViewer$7.run(CommitFileDiffViewer.jav
a:249)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContribution
Item.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501
)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.jav
a:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.j
ava:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.jav
a:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLa
uncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.ja
va:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen, if the file is not within a project that is imported in Eclipse. If the repository you are looking at contains Eclipse projects anyway, importing them should help. Otherwise you can import the repository content as a "general project" into Eclipse.

There is an [EGit bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=424585) describing the same problem you experience. You may want to vote for this bug. Importing as a project into Eclipse feels more like a workaround for the problem than a solution.